# Continuous Random Variable with constant moments?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I would like to know if there exists a measure $\rho$ on the positive real line such that its moments $\int_0^{\infty} x^j d\rho(x)$ are equal to a constant (for example equal to one) for all $j=0,\dots,n,\dots$ (or for $j\leq n$ for any $n$). 
In other words, if there exists a density function (equal to zero on the negative real part) such that its characteristic function is $e^{it}$.

Comment: $e^{it}$ is a continuous map, and positive define, which is $1$ at $0$, so it's a characteristic function. Now, we have to see whether the law whose characteristic function is this map is concentrated on the positive real line. Well, $\rho=\delta_1$ works, but it seems too trivial.

Comment: and how to see that? Or any reference for that?

Comment: The first assertion comes from a theorem due to Bochner. But it's not necessary here.

Comment: Notice that constant moments imply zero variance. What does it tell you about the purported density function?

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 3):

The (unique) random variable whose characteristic function is $t\mapsto e^{it}$ is associated to the measure $\delta_1$, that is 
$$\delta_1(A)=\begin{cases}
1&\mbox{ if }1\in A,\\
0&\mbox{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
This is not a continuous random variable.

Answer (score 3):

(With no characteristic function.)

Note that $$\int(x-1)^2\,\mathrm d\rho(x)=\int x^2\,\mathrm d\rho(x)-2\int x\,\mathrm d\rho(x)+\int 1\,\mathrm d\rho(x).
$$
Hence, if
$$
\int x^2\,\mathrm d\rho(x)=\int x\,\mathrm d\rho(x)=\int 1\,\mathrm d\rho(x),
$$
then the set $\mathbb R\setminus\{1\}$ has measure zero with respect to $\rho$. (No hypothesis on some other moments is necessary.)